# VBA keep getting error trying to reference SQL database

Tags: sql, vba, excel

My program basically opens up any .MDB file and then shows the file within the spreadsheet, however I keep getting this error(despite the code working and the file opening up on excel).

The error that comes up is "Run time error 429, Active X component Can't create object"

Here is the code that I have and I will write above the line that gets highlighted when I hit debug.

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim strFileToOpen As String
 ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
 strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
 (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
 FileFilter:="All Files *.* (*.*),")


 Workbooks.Open fileName:=strFileToOpen
 frmMain.TextBox1.Text = strFileToOpen

 Exit Sub

 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim fileName As String
 Dim copyDestination As String
 Dim copyFile As String
 Dim fso

 If frmMain.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
 MsgBox "No File Selected"
 Else
 fileName = frmMain.TextBox1.Value

 copyDestination = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sales_Orders.mdb"

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 fso.copyFile fileName, copyDestination, True

 Set fso = Nothing

 MsgBox "File copied to current workbook directory!"
 End If

 'SQL Statements

Dim db As Database
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim td As TableDef
Dim dbname As String

' Open the database. replace "c:\DBfile.mdb" with your
' database file name
```

'THIS LINE SET DB = OPENDATABASE GETS HIGHLIGHTED WHEN I HIT DEBUG

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(copyDestination)

' List the table names.
For Each td In db.TableDefs
' if you want to display also the system tables, replace the line
' below with:  List1.AddItem td.Name
   If td.Attributes = 0 Then ListBox1.AddItem td.Name
Next td
db.Close


 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 Unload Me


 End Sub
```

As noted in the code,Set db = OpenDatabase(copyDestination) is the line that gets highlighted when I hit debug. Any idea why that is going on?

Comment: Have you tried it as `Set db = Workbooks.OpenDatabase(copyDestination)` ?

Comment: il try that right now one moment

Comment: @Jeeped, now it gives me a new error, run time error 13, type mismatch. when i hit debug, points to the line just editted,    Set db = Workbooks.OpenDatabase(copyDestination)

Comment: @Jeeped any idea?

Comment: You have this tagged as `excel-vba` but I want to confirm you are working within `excel-vba` and not `access-vba`.

Comment: Reference ADODB and work with that. [Docs.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado#t=201703141815563808061).

Comment: @Jeeped , yes I am working with excel macro.

Comment: Adding `dim db as object` and then running `Set db = Workbooks.OpenDatabase(copyDestination)` works for me (although I had to change to a `Sales_Orders.accdb` filename).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OpenDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193543.aspx) method is a member of the [Workbooks object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841074.aspx). You cannot call it ad hoc without a reference to the Workbooks object.

```
Dim db as Object
Set db = Workbooks.OpenDatabase(copyDestination)
```

Declare your `db` as an object, not a database.

Comment: It seemed to be working fine, then when I went to go select another database after this line was giving an error , run time error 438,  object doesnt support this property or method. And the offending line is: For Each td In db.TableDefs.

Comment: Well, the generic object is not realizing it has tabledefs. You could change over to ADO or DAO as mentioned in comments or simply loop through the header row of the worksheet that was created.